# How to add product to cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

I want to add a product with a bunch of options in the current cart via controller. How should I do this? And then what do I need to do if I want to remove it later on?

Comment: I believe there are 2 approaches used currently.  The old approach is used by the current checkout page which uses the controller to add items to the cart.  At some point we'll be refactoring to use the interfaces in Quote to add items to the cart and passing those items an extensible object that specifies the custom options for that item.  That's how we handled non-simple products in the cart APIs.  You can look at the REST api documentation for info on specifying custom options for items ( http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html ; quoteCartItemRepository).

Comment: I didn't know such a reference exists, million thanks

Comment: Also in a Magento 2 instance with custom services you can get your own API reference by hitting http://BASEURL/swagger  .

Answer (score 3):

In your customer controller :-
Add product into cart

```
 class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

         /**
          * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
          */
         protected $cart;
         /**
          * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
          */
         protected $product;
         /**
          * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
          */
         protected $messageManager;

         public function __construct(
             \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
             \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
             \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
             \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
         ) {
             $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
             $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
             $this->cart = $cart;
             $this->product = $product;
             $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
             parent::__construct($context);
         }
         public function execute()
         {
             try {
                 $params = array();
                 $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity
                 /*get product id*/
                 $pId = '1';//productId
                 $_product = $this->product->load($pId);
                 if ($_product) {
                     $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                     $this->cart->save();
                 }

                 $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart successfully.'));
             } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                 $this->messageManager->addException(
                     $e,
                     __('%1', $e->getMessage())
                 );
             } catch (\Exception $e) {
                 $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
             }
             /*cart page*/
             $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/index');


         }
    }
```

Remove product :-

1:- get item id from quote.

2:- remove code :-

```
   try {
            //$id => item id 
            $this->cart->removeItem($id)->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t remove the item.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
        }
```

Comment: This works but the mini cart top right does not update

Comment: I tried your code but its not working. I am trying to add product to cart using observer event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` but the code doesn't work. Could you please let me know where $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; is used?

Comment: $this->messageManager is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
   save the cart through sku
<?php
 namespace GreenPlank\Addtocart\Controller\Index;

  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
 */
protected $cart;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
 */
protected $product;

protected $productRepository;

// protected $_productFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    // $this->productFactory = $_productFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    try {
        $params = array();
        $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity
        /*get product id*/
        // custom-price-set
        // $params['price']='100';
        //productId
        $skuId =$_GET['sku'];
        // $_product = $this->productFactory->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
        $_product = $this->productRepository->get($skuId);
        // $_product = $this->product->load($pId);
        
        if ($_product){
            $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
            $this->cart->save();
        }

        $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart successfully.'));
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException(
            $e,
            __('%1', $e->getMessage())
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
    }
    /*cart page*/
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
save the product through
<?php

namespace Indexiz\Addtocart\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $cart;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $product;

    protected $productRepository;

    // protected $_productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        // \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        // $this->productFactory = $_productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $params = array();
            $params['qty'] = '1';//product quantity
            /*get product id*/
            // custom-price-set
            // $params['price']='100';
            //productId
            $skuId =$_GET['sku'];
            // $_product = $this->productFactory->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
            $_product = $this->productRepository->get($skuId);
            // $_product = $this->product->load($pId);
            
            if ($_product){
                $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                $this->cart->save();
            }

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Add to cart successfully.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException(
                $e,
                __('%1', $e->getMessage())
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('error.'));
        }
        /*cart page*/
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('/checkout/cart/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $buttonBuyNow = __('Buy Now'); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); 
    $sku=$_product->getSku();
?>
<a href="addtocart?sku=<?php echo $sku; ?> "   title="">
                <div class="actions">
                    <button type="submit" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonBuyNow ?>" class="action primary-data tocart" id="product-addtocart-button"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonBuyNow ?></button>
                </div>
            </div>
</a>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .primary-data{
        display: inline-block;
    height: 52px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 500;
    border: 1px solid #ed2228;
    background-color: #ed2228;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
```