# Magento 2: How to update mini cart after add product to cart from API?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, mini-cart

I'm working on a task that need an API endpoint for adding product to cart in Magento 2.

My code do the job "add product to cart" properly (it add product to cart and when I go to .../checkout/cart I can see it.

```
$params = array('product' => $cardId, 'qty' => 1);

$product = $this->productRepository->getById($cardId);
$this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$this->cart->save();
```

But I need to update the mini cart also.
I searched google and this is the best solution that I found:

Create file etc/frontend/sections.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="rest/V1/badgemakerapi/addToCart">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

In the tutorial, the part

> name="rest/V1/badgemakerapi/addToCart"

is actually

> name="frontname/controller/action"

but because I don't have controller, I have to change it to API route

I noticed that in Checkout module, magento 2 core team does the same thing:

```
    <action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/payment-information">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
        <section name="last-ordered-items"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/guest-carts/*/payment-information">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/guest-carts/*/selected-payment-method">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
    <action name="rest/*/V1/carts/*/selected-payment-method">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
```

The problem is I can not update mini cart using this method.

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In this case, are you making the `addToCart` API call from the client's web page, and you want to update the minicart badge and items without reloading the page? Or is the issue that even after reloading the page, the minicart still isn't updated?

Comment: @thaddeusmt: It's the issue even after I manually reload the page, the mini cart is still the same. I think it will be considered a bug in testing phase. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now running into this same issue. It appears to be related to the way the cart is cached in the browser's "local storage". I don't actually have a solution yet, unfortunately, but clearing the local storage in Chome refreshed my minicart.

There are some open bugs in Magento's GitHub:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3625
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2339

It looks like a long standing bug. Hopefully they will fix it soon.

Here are some related SE questions I'm working from right now:

- [How to trigger a minicart update after adding to cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98869/how-to-trigger-a-minicart-update-after-adding-to-cart)
- [Magento 2: Syncing Backend and Frontend State/Cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93398/magento-2-syncing-backend-and-frontend-state-cache)

My (current) solution is to request that the minicart component refresh by default on page load. This way if the user updates the cart via an API request somewhere else, when they reload the Magento site the cart refreshes.

Specifically, I override the `minicart.js` file and modified it to force the `customerData` to refresh in the `initialize` method every page load:

```
initialize: function () {
    var self = this,
        cartData = customerData.get('cart');
    ....
    // always clear minicart local storage cache, since we might be updating it via API call
    customerData.reload(['cart'], false);
    // if (cartData().website_id !== window.checkout.websiteId) {
    //     customerData.reload(['cart'], false);
    // }
    return this._super();
},
```